# Mongodb exception in initAndListen

Tags: mongodb, exception

My `MongoDB` server was full so `Mongod` service could not start. There was a specific db that I didn't need, so I have deleted its file from the `dbpath`.
Now when I try to start the service again I'm getting the following error in the log:

```
*** SERVER RESTARTED ***
...
.. DBName_Example Assertion failure isOk() src/mongo/db/storage/extend.h 80
...
.. exception in initAndListen: 0 assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent.h, terminating
...
```

I tried to run `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --repair` but I'm getting the same error.

I know that was a bad idea to delete the file, but I have no way to restore it. How can I fix it considering that the data is important and I need to keep it.

Comment: In the dbpath do you have the `mongod.lock` file?

Comment: I have created empty file with the same db name and now it is working. How can I delete a db while my mongo service is down?

Comment: Maybe it's better to cleanup some logfiles and other things (old kernels/clean some cache/...), then change the mongo-port (so applications wouldn't connect), restart your service, drop the unneeded database. After that, you can restart your mongod as normal. This only for a standalone MongoDB.